# In the export of xCode archive how disable target signing from command line

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, command-line, continuous-integration

I have an xCode project generated with **Unity for iOS**.

Once the build is finished and the archive is generated I try to export the archive with the Enterprise method from the command line.

When I distribute app from xCode directly and I get to the signing step, we can see this: **UnityFramework.framework: No profile required**. If I click next, the export will be done without problems and I will have an .ipa

[image]

The concern is that I want to do this as part of CI/CD pipeline with command line.

Here is the command :
`xcodebuild -exportArchive -exportOptionsPlist /path/exportOptions.plist -archivePath '/pathToArchive' -exportPath /exportPath`

Here is the plist :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>destination</key>
    <string>export</string>
    <key>method</key>
    <string>enterprise</string>
    <key>provisioningProfiles</key>
    <dict>
        <key>com.inhouse.test</key>
        <string>In House Test Profile</string>
    </dict>
    <key>signingCertificate</key>
    <string>Apple Distribution</string>
    <key>signingStyle</key>
    <string>manual</string>
    <key>teamID</key>
    <string>XXXXXXXX</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Here is the error message :

> error: exportArchive: UnityFramework.framework does not support provisioning profiles.

I have the impression that the problem I am having is that from the command line there is UnityDesign.app which is signed but also the UnityFramework.framework which does not require a profile. So I always come across the same error at the signing stage.

Does anyone have a solution to deactivate UnityFramework.framework signing or another solution ?

**UPDATED SOLUTION :**

The solution was to use Fatlande `update_code_signing_settings`

the script looks like this :

```rb
      update_code_signing_settings(
        path: "./Build_iOS/Unity-iPhone.xcodeproj",
        use_automatic_signing: true,
        team_id: "TEAM ID",
        bundle_identifier: "BUNDLE ID",
        code_sign_identity: "iPhone Developer",
        targets: "Unity-iPhone"
      )
```

Comment: are you using fastlane ?

Comment: yes I'm using fastlane to build and export.

Comment: can you put the fastfile here too? I have had a similar issue with fastlane, for tvos tho, eventually fixed it by using update code signing methods to overwrite the configs. In case your fastlane is not doing it, I may help with that

Comment: thanks I checked update code signing methods and found "targets" param. With this parameter fastlane will just sign my application and will skip signing the framework.

Comment: Cool, I was able to use similar approach. Skipping didint work for my case though, so I have to override settings twice (disable auto sign -> update details for non-framwork target -> enable auto sign for framework). weird way to deal tbh, but at least it worked after several days of annoyance